# Volunteer/seedling in Toronto garden

Tags: species-identification, botany

What species of plant is this?

- Location: Toronto area (Ontario, Canada)
- Date: July 7, 2022
- Conditions: Acid soil in shade
- Height: Approx. 11 inches
- Description: Younger leaves resemble tomato leaves. Main leaves are serrated. Opposite.

[image]

---

**August 25, 2022**

[image]

[image]

---

**September 6, 2022**

[image]

Comment: I think the leaves are simple pinnate and alternating, though it is hard to tell from the photo. I want to say Dahlia, but the leaves don't look quite right.

Comment: @bob1 Thanks. If you click on the photo a couple of times in your browser, it should show the full photo, which is quite large. From there, you can zoom in. When we do that, I think it's a bit clearer that the leaves are opposite, not alternating.

Comment: Thanks. Opposite is correct. Not Dahlia - too hairy.

Comment: Can you post more photos of this plant? Closeups of the stem, roots (if you decide to kill or move it), and both surfaces of the leaves may help; however, flower photos are likely necessary for you to get a definitive identification (ideally from multiple angles).

Comment: Nice updates. Should help quite a bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that this is one of the beggarticks, in the genus [*Bidens*](https://www.inaturalist.org/taxa/50204-Bidens). There are several possibilities in your area, including [*B. connata*](https://www.inaturalist.org/taxa/130988-Bidens-connata), [*B. frondosa*](https://www.inaturalist.org/taxa/51712-Bidens-frondosa), and [*B. vulgata*](https://www.inaturalist.org/taxa/75768-Bidens-vulgata). I think more detail would be needed for a finer identification.

The main features pointing me this way are the opposite, compound leaves, and the distinctive shape of the leaflets (ovate-lanceolate, serrated margins, attenuate tips).

Comment: Based on the number and type of bracts beneath the flowering head (aka "calyculus bractlets", about 8, not "foliaceous" but merely herbaceous), and the shape of the leaves (3-foliate), I think this is probably [_Bidens frondosa_](http://www.efloras.org/florataxon.aspx?flora_id=1&taxon_id=103917).